# Need help using Array with for loops, if statements and while loops

Tags: arrays, lua, iteration

So I'm having issues creating what I thought would be a 2 minute endeavor. I myself have been studying Java for 2 years but I'm finding it hard to "adjust" some of the things I've learned to LUA. I want to make an array of usernames and want to check the array in it's entirety to use in a if statement for example.

Here is what I've made and in no way do I consider it complete so I hope I can get assistance with this.

I'm open to completely rewriting this so any and all input is appreciated.

```
local function main()
    UserNames = {}
    UserNames[1] = "Maximus"
    UserNames[2] = "John"

    print("Enter your Username")
    inputUserName = io.read("*l")

    for i=1,2 do
        --print(v)
        if inputUserName == UserNames[i] then
            print("Username Found")
            print("Welcome", UserNames[i])
            break
        else
            while inputUserName ~= UserNames[i] do
                print("ERROR, Username Doesn't Exist")
                print("Enter your Username")
                inputUserName = io.read("*l")
            end
        end
    end
end
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Delaney! This is a good first question to be asking. Perhaps the documentation over at Lua's site would be of use while you're trying to step over to it's usage. Depending on your version, you will find alternate code. Newer versions do some neat stuff with modules, and the older ones do some interesting things with tables. Check it out here: [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/).

Comment: Also, it's personal preference, but I like to capitalize my function names and camel case my variables. Of course, the standard libraries are all in lowercase or camel depending on where you look, so it isn't consistent. It comes down, again, to preference. I come from C style langs, so that's how I go about it. Semicolons, although most times semantic sugar, come in handy for inline anonymous functions. It is good practice to make use of them on your line endings. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change a whole lot at all, which is lovely! I've taken a little creative liberty in your Lua file here and am going to cut these up into little segmented functions that make things more manageable for you.

In short, it comes down to just iterating over the array to trigger a specific conditional, to step out of our while. With a bit of tweaking, like below, you should have what you need to get through this iteration problem.

```
-- Here's a thought, store these within a separate Lua file and import them using modules!
-- Or better yet, learn a little SQL and make it as secure as you can. :)
UserNames = {};
UserNames[1] = "Maximus";
UserNames[2] = "John";

-- If the username input is contained within UserNames array.
-- Returns: boolean
local function CheckUsername(usernameString)
    for k, v in pairs(UserNames) do
        if (usernameString == v) then
            return true;
        end
    end
    return false;
end

-- Recieve input from the command line. Will wait for completion.
-- Returns: nothing yet.
local function ReceiveUsername()
    local input = nil;
    local matchFound = false;
    local cancelled = false;

    while (matchFound == false and cancelled == false) do

        print("Please, enter your username:");
        input = io.read("*l");

        -- This is probably the most self-explanitory function I've ever written. I'm so happy.
        result = CheckUsername(input);

        if (result == true) then
            matchFound = true;
        end

        if (input == "exit") then
            cancelled = true;
        end

    end

    if (matchFound) then
        print("Welcome, "..input);
    end

    if (cancelled) then
        print("Cancelled the loop.");
    end

    --  Apply more switch cases here. (I wish Lua had switch cases, but you can't win 'em all.)    
    --  Optional: 
    --  Return key, value pair for later iteration.
    --  Make the user a table of values that contains different priviledges. :)
end

local function main()
    -- The main brains of receiving input.
    ReceiveUsername();
end

-- Cache all our functionality before we call main.
main();
```

Functions list is as follows:

- `main`: Right now, just calls `ReceiveUsername` and nothing else. Main should only ever really call one or two things max. Keep it pure.
- `ReceiveInput`: Here is where we do our iteration. We cache our variables up top and then say `While we aren't cancelling or matching, keep on getting input until we do. Then just use what we have later in the function.`
- `CheckUsername`: A simple helper function to compare a string against our table. It's succinct; just look it over.

Comment: Thanks for the information James, I still have the issue of if I enter the second username first or an incorrect one it says it doesn't exist. Also if I enter an incorrect Username then a correct one it says it doesn't exist. Any ideas how to amend this?

Comment: Heyo Delaney, I went ahead and updated that example and my answer accordingly. I was in the middle of work after a long morning of rewriting an application again and again so I was braindead. Please check my revision; I think it has some code you'll like to look at. If you need a module example, please give it a google. If you have questions about it's implementation you'll find the answers you seek using that good ol' search engine.